# cp: target ... is not a directory - why does this happen?

Tags: command-line, directory, mkdir

```
alan:~/LIME_SRC/soapySDR$ mkdir mybuild
alan:~/LIME_SRC/soapySDR$ cd mybuild
alan:~/LIME_SRC/soapySDR/mybuild$ cp /LIME_SRC/soapySDR/name "CMakeLists.txt" /LIME_SRC/soapySDR/mybuild
cp: target '/LIME_SRC/soapySDR/mybuild' is not a directory
```

Comment: You're working in `~/LIME_SRC/soapySDR` but copying to `/LIME_SRC/soapySDR/...`.

Comment: `~/LIME_SRC` does not equal `/LIME_SRC`. What are you trying to achieve? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 5):

you must use

```
cp LIME_SRC/soapySDR/name "CMakeLists.txt" LIME_SRC/soapySDR/mybuild
```

or

```
cp ~/LIME_SRC/soapySDR/name "CMakeLists.txt" ~/LIME_SRC/soapySDR/mybuild
```

instead of

```
cp /LIME_SRC/soapySDR/name "CMakeLists.txt" /LIME_SRC/soapySDR/mybuild
```

because your repertory `mybuild` is located in `/home/alan/LIME_SRC/soapySDR/mybuild` and not in `/LIME_SRC/soapySDR/mybuild`

Comment: I think you should explicitly mention that `~` stands for the home directory, i.e. `/home/alan` probably...

Comment: i deduct it with the information of his question, we see the user name